# SQL Get better results when searching with an OR statement

Tags: sql

I have a simple name search query that looks for first name and last name. I need to be able to have the output be either and OR statement if one field is null or an AND statement if both are.

```
 SELECT USERNAME,
 FIRSTNAME,
 LASTNAME FROM USERS WHERE FIRSTNAME LIKE @FIRSTNAME OR LASTNAME LIKE @LASTNAME
```

Comment: What database engine are you using?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Hi @James, do tell us more about what you need. Some example data would be nice also...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  SELECT USERNAME,  FIRSTNAME,  LASTNAME 
  FROM USERS
  WHERE (@FIRSTNAME IS NULL OR FIRSTNAME LIKE @FIRSTNAME)
    AND (@LASTNAME IS NULL OR LASTNAME LIKE @LASTNAME )
```

Answer (score 0):

Could just do a check to see if that field is null first, then do comparison and also include % character for like syntax

```
SELECT USERNAME,
    FIRSTNAME,
    LASTNAME
FROM USERS
WHERE (
        @FIRSTNAME IS NULL
        OR FIRSTNAME LIKE '%' + @FIRSTNAME + '%'
        )
    AND (
        @LASTNAME IS NULL
        OR LASTNAME LIKE '%' + @LASTNAME + '%'
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

It is better to avoid `OR` because of performance. So you can try something like this.

```
SELECT USERNAME,
 FIRSTNAME,
 LASTNAME 
FROM USERS 
WHERE FIRSTNAME LIKE isnull(@FIRSTNAME + '%', firstname) 
and LASTNAME LIKE isnull(@LASTNAME + '%', lastname)
and isnull(@firstname, @lastname) is not null -- return empty result when both @ are null
```